# How to check if DbGeography objects overlap

Tags: sql, polygon, geospatial, spatial

There is an 'Overlap' method in DbSpatialServices Class to check if two DbGeometry objects overlap each other. How can I check if DbGeography objects overlap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For whoever it may be useful, I have eventually used 'Intersects' method which seems to be working fine